Button styling when using SelectionPlaceHolder
I am trying to create a button to export a user-selected image. According to the documentation for button, "Button[label, None, BaseStyle->stylename] inherits button functionality from the definition of stylename in the stylesheet. Such styles typically allow
[SelectionPlaceholder] to be used in label to represent the currently selected text." This approach works functionally, but the label of the produced button is a copy of the (Export invocation) action to be performed upon button press. That is, there is no separate ability to control the contents of the label. This question addresses the same issue, but does not provide an answer. I am hoping that there has been some progress since the question was originally posed eleven years ago.
Here is a naive example of the problem:
Button[Defer[Export["image.png", \[SelectionPlaceholder]]], None, BaseStyle->"CopyEvaluate"]

And here is the a picture of the resulting button. Note the less-than-helpful button label.

Pressing the button when the image is selected indeed exports the image.
I have tried several approaches to improving the appearance of the label, including this one, without success:

Instead of an inline action expression, use a function with a
descriptive name. The function name is shown in the label, but the
function invocation brackets (e.g. f[]) are also displayed;
Use the Interpretation function to change the label. However, the action upon button press is to export an image of the selection
placeholder instead of the selected image;
Various combinations of Defer and Evaluate, all without success.

Here are my questions:
1. Has there been any new features added to MMA since the original question was posed that might address this issue, or are there any other suggestions on how to fix the problem?
2. In addition to exporting the image, the naive approach produces a new output cell containing the output of the export function:

Is there a way to avoid corrupting the notebook with this inserted cell?
3. The executed code can be found in Core.nb stylesheet in the CopyEvaluate style cell:
Cell[
    StyleData["CopyEvaluate", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["GenericButton"]],
    StyleMenuListing -> None,
    ButtonStyleMenuListing -> Automatic,
    ButtonBoxOptions -> {
        ButtonFunction :> (
            FrontEndExecute[{
                SelectionCreateCell[InputNotebook[], All], 
                NotebookApply[InputNotebook[], #, All], 
                SelectionEvaluate[InputNotebook[], All]
            }] &
        )
    }
]

Is there a way to adapt this ButtonFunction (possibly using its options ButtonSource and ButtonData) to solve the label problem?
I am running MMA V13.2 on a MacBook M2 with MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1.

I don't think you need any fiddling with ButtonFunction etc. Just use plain Button and give it the action you want. In this case, reading the current selection with NotebookRead, then exporting it to a predefined file. Note that NotebookRead will give you a box structure of selected expression, so it will be something like GraphicsBox[...] for an image. You need to convert this back to the expression, e.g. Image[...], for which you can use ToExpression.
Button["Export Selected Image", 
  Export["image.png", ToExpression@NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]]]


nice solution. Can you add a few words to your answer explaining why the ToExpression was required? This was not obvious to me.

@SpencerRugaber, I've added a short explanation.

Nice addition. I have accepted your answer.
